# How can I backup a directory to NTFS while preserving Unix file attributes?

Tags: filesystems, permissions, files, backup, ntfs

I want to make a backup of my home directory to an NTFS partition (an unfortunate limitation). However, when I last tried using just `cp`, the attributes (owner, etc) went away. How can I make a backup while still preserving these attributes? My first instinct is to make a tarball, but I'm not sure if this will work.

For reference, I'm running Ubuntu Raring devel.

Comment: A tarball will preserve the attributes. Note, if you have ACL(s), tarballs will not preserve that unless it's been compiled to support it.

Comment: Most recent linux distros and recent versions of `tar` support ACLs by default, I think...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, the NTFS permissions model and the Unix one don't look alike at all. There simply is no way to sanely map between them.

Use `tar`, but read the documentation carefully so all permissions get faithfully stored (including ACLs and SELinux contexts).

Comment: what's an ACL? if I haven't used ACLs or SELinux contexts on purpose, can I assume that I don't have them? if it's relevant, I'm running Ubuntu Raring devel

Comment: @strugee ACLs are advanced POSIX Access Control Lists which allow significantly finer control on a per-user basis. As with SELinux, if you don't explicitly activated or used them, you probably don't have to worry them.

Answer (score 2):

I find it interesting how nobody ever gives examples and assumes the 'backup using tar' is a helpful enough answer. It isn't, by my standards. Here's how I do it:

```
ionice -c2 -n5 nice -n9 tar czvf - /media/somelinuxdrivepath | split -b 16m - /media/usb/ntfsmounted/back.tar.gz.
```

and then to unpack:

```
ionice -c2 -n5 nice -n9 cat /media/usb/ntfsmounted/back.tar.gz.* | tar xzvf - /media/somenewlinuxpath
```

I use ionice, nice and split in 16 MB files because the mounted NTFS usb drive is slow and RAM would fill up entirely without it, and/or the linux system would just freeze and crash. Your mileage may vary, depending on your hardware.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `tar` to dump the data and `getfacl`/`setfacl` for storing/restoring the ACLs. Even if NTFS supported UNIX permissions you'd have to ensure mapping od user/group IDs and names, which `tar` does for you automatically (be aware that some - usually rather ancient or non-mainstream - versions of the utility don't store user/group names, only the numerical IDs).