# How do file permissions work with partition filesystem?

Tags: permissions, filesystems

If I store a file in `ext2`, `ext3`, or `ext4` formatted partition, it's permission is saved. I mean, I can have different permissions for different files in `extX` partition. However, If I store a file in `NTFS` partition, I can't change it's permission. The permission is depends on how `NTFS` partition is mounted. For example, with nautilus, all file permissions will be `rwxrwxrwx`.

It can bring some problems if I backed up some files that need different permissions from `extX`  to `NTFS`. Two files with `rw-------` and `rw-r--r--` permissions will have `rwxrwxrwx` permissions if stored in `NTFS`.

My points here is (which basically one point in the title):

1. Where is the information about file permission stored?

   - If it stored in OS configuration, how can I get exactly the same
     permission if I reinstall the OS.
   - If it stored in the file it self, does it means file state is
     changed when copying from `extX` to `NTFS` and vice versa?
2. If I have a lot of files with different permissions, then copy all
   of them to `NTFS`. Is it possible to get back the exact permissions
   for all file if I copy all of them back to `extX`?
3. Is it possible to have different file permissions in `NTFS`?

Comment: Related: [How can I backup a directory to NTFS while preserving Unix file attributes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73344/how-can-i-backup-a-directory-to-ntfs-while-preserving-unix-file-attributes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The permissions are stored in file system metadata.  NTFS and ext3/4 file systems differ substantially in how they store metadata.
One solution would be to create a tar file of the source directory (with or without compression), writing the resulting file to the NTFS file system.
When the content of the tar archive is extracted to a ext3/4 file system the permissions and ownership are preserved.

For example:

```
tar cvf /mnt/ntfs_share/archive.tar /source_ext4/*
```

Or, with bzip2 compression:

```
tar cjvf /mnt/ntfs_share/archive.tar.bz2 /source_ext4/*
```